# Промежуток времени в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Имеется число, равное количеству секунд в промежутке времени. Задача - перевести это время в более читаемый вид. Например, 4d 05:00:00.
`var d=new Date();
d.setSeconds()` выдает что-то неадекватное.Судя по всему, она берет текущий день.
Преобразование даты в строку не подходит, поскольку так отваливается сортировка footable.
Может быть, есть подходящий тип данных javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var d=new Date(); d.setSeconds() выдает что-то неадекватное.Судя по
>   всему, она берет текущий день.

Да, всё верно, при создании `Date` без аргументов берётся текущее время. Для вашего случая нужно создать `Date` с параметром количества мсек, то есть что-то вроде:

```
var d = new Date(seconds * 1000);
```

Для более удобного преобразования даты можно использовать, например, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Чтобы не отваливалась [сортировка у FooTable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/components/sorting.html), нужно указать `data-sort-value` у `td` равное количеству секунд.

Comment: Добавление data-sort-value решило проблему, для отображения времени формирую строку, ибо Date не может выводить 0 дней